# How to get all jenkins variables

Tags: python, jenkins, environment-variables

I want to write a python script to get list of "jenkins" variables and show them.
I wrote this, but it returned all environment variables instead of jenkins variables.

```
import os
print os.environ
```

How can I get them in python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a specific set of built-in variable that a base Jenkins install adds to each execution step; here is a list from the reference:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-below

As Slav says, these are just like any other environment variable, and if you want to access one you would just ask for it by name e.g., for $WORKSPACE, you would use os.environ['WORKSPACE']

You could enumerate the variables at the url above in a list ['WORKSPACE', ...] and print them that way...

Comment: It's good, but I think jenkins has more variables than they listed in that link!

Comment: It does. To get the full list, do what I suggested: get EnvInject, configure build to clean inherited system environment variables, and then just look at everything that's left with a 'set' command on either of the command prompts

Comment: well, I installed it, but I need to use this plugin remotely by using command in an script. can you help me?

Comment: well, I installed it, but I need to use this plugin remotely by using command in an script. can you help me?    I mean that I want to run my script and by using it for creating job (that I'v done before),user can set valuables.how can i use this plugin in my script?

Comment: What do you mean by 'use this plugin remotely'? Do you mean call Jenkins externally, or when running a jenkins job on a slave?

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins variables **are** environment variables. There isn't really anything that separates them.

You can use [**EnvInject**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin to clean the Jenkins environment of all OS environment variables that are inherited, this way you are left with "just Jenkins environment variables", but careful as this may break your tools as none of the paths will be set.

If you want to view just the Build Parameters, you can use the Jenkins API for each job, or parse the job's XML file

Comment: How can I parse the job's xml file with python script?